# How to get Gamma case?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

As there is new case in CSGO **(Gamma Case)** and it has some good skins but its like damn hard to get. I have been playing from weeks still i did not get neither i have seen any of guy getting this so **is there any specific rule to get this** or we have to play Competitive match for this?

I think its related to some particular map or anything else like play competitive or death match in particular map like Italy/dust etc??

Also i have heard that now value has decreased the drop rate so now users are getting drop like hell, so is there any link/article where i can read about this? I have tried but not getting anything.

Hope to get good reply or more info on this topic. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from buying them yourself from the Market, there is no certain and guarantied way you'd get a Case drop. Everyone gets their cases in exactly the same way - they play the game trough official ways (MM, DM, Casual) and get case drops. It used to be 2 case drops per week and 2 skin drops per week, now I don't know the exact numbers now.

Comment: @Leothelion It works like this: There is a timer than runs from Wednesday to Wednesday where if you level up you get a guaranteed random drop. If you have the new operation(wildfire) it's a wildfire skin, otherwise it's a random skin. 

So while it is possible to get 2 skins in a week, you'll have to wait a while for your next guaranteed drop.

Comment: @Riley thank you for info. What about drop rate?

Comment: @Leothelion From what I know the whole thing is totally random. I got my other case on inferno, dont recall which one it is. I opened the new case and got some "eh" skin that i didnt like out of it (typical). i think it was for the bizon. I sold it. In fairness if you get a new case it is better to sell it right after it comes out, but if you dont you should open it. the off chance you might get something super valuable (espescially since it just came out) means even the low end skins sell for a pretty penny, but the prices plummet very fast after the case release.

Comment: @Leothelion The cases are literally gambling. you have some crazy odds of getting the high value items (which is why they are high value to begin with) and the low value stuff is almost worthless. If you get a new case the day it comes out, open it. Regardless of when, if the update that added it came out that day, open the case. even the cheapest items will sell better than the cost of a key, and the more expensive ones will be worth a fortune but only for a VERY short time. These prices fall VERY fast as more cases are opened, so the sooner the better really.

Comment: Cleaned up quite a few comments here. Please try to avoid extended discussion in comments, if possible, and create a [chat room instead.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/new)